# Text files in the path configuration file

Tags: requirejs

I'm using the `text` plugin of RequireJS. Is it possible to reference a text file in the path configuration file? I've tried

```
require.config({
   paths: {
       'myTemplate': 'text!templates/myTemplate.html'
   }
});
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because RequireJS plugins are designed to be used as part of a require command, not in the config.

Try:

```
require.config({
   paths: {
       'myTemplate': 'templates/myTemplate.html'
   }
});
```

and in your module:

```
define(
    ['text!myTemplate'],

    function () {}
)
```

Comment: @RamenRecon and if I would like to have a path for my template folder f.e. ```'tmpl': 'templates/'``` can you do that?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 as well. This is with version 2.1.2 of require. If I specify a baseUrl of './' it tries to search for the './.myTemplate' file as well.

Comment: hmmm, can you use r.js with this configuration? I'd love to be able to concatenate all my files as per this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152372/optimize-requirejs-front-end-application

Answer (score 4):

RamenRecon's answer helped, but in my case I think it was slightly confusing by using myTemplate for the path and template name. The key I found is to only substitute the Path, but not the actual file name. As a result, to abstract the path to /subSystem/templates/myTemplate.htm using require and the path configuration, set the configuration as follows:

```
require.config({
   paths: {
      templatePath: 'subsystem/templates'
   }
});
```

And then in your module definition:

```
define(['text!templatePath/myTemplate.htm'],
   function(template) {}
);
```

Comment: But unfortunately, it's not _enough_. I'm using require.paths to handle cache-busting, but cannot use the text plugin to do this.